# Android - Change text of button in a selected row

Tags: java, android, algorithm, android-listview, android-button

i've tried everything but nothing have worked.
I have a listView like this:

```
   [ checkbox ] | [textview] | [button]
```

What i'm trying to do is change the text of [button] only in the row witch [ checkbox ] is checked.
Here is the problematic block of code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final ViewHolder vh;
        final View conv;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater vi=(LayoutInflater)pContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=vi.inflate(R.layout.rest_dishes_item, null);
            conv=convertView;
            final Button b[];
            b=new Button[itens.size()];
            vh=new ViewHolder();
            vh.txt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dish_name);
            vh.checkBox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dish_item);
            vh.qnt=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qnt);

            vh.quantidade=new Quantidade[itens.size()];
            for(int i=0;i<itens.size();i++){
                b[i]=(Button)conv.findViewById(R.id.qnt);
                vh.quantidade[i].quantidade=1;
                vh.quantidade[i].order=i;
            }
            vh.qnt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for(int i=0;i<itens.size();i++){
                        Titem item=itens.get(i);
                        if(item.isCheck()){
                            vh.quantidade[i].quantidade++;
                            //Log.d("teste",i+""+vh.quantidade[i].quantidade);
                            b[i].setText(String.valueOf(vh.quantidade[i].quantidade));
                        }
                        else if(!item.isCheck()){
                            Log.d("teste",i+"1");
                            b[i].setText(String.valueOf(1));
                        }
                    }

                }

            });
                    //(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qnt);



            convertView.setTag(vh);


            vh.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CheckBox box=(CheckBox) arg0;
                    Titem item=(Titem)box.getTag();

                    item.setCheck(box.isChecked());
                }
            });
        }else{
            vh=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Titem item=itemList.get(position);



        vh.txt.setText(item.getName());
        vh.checkBox.setText(item.getName());
        vh.checkBox.setChecked(item.isCheck());
        vh.checkBox.setTag(item);

        //Log.d("teste","chegou aqui");

        return convertView;
    }
```

With this code the text of the buttons doesn't change at all, no matter which button i click his text still "1".

Without the line:

```
b[i].setText(String.valueOf(1));
```

The button of a checked row has his text changed like i want. But When i click a button of a non checked row, the clicked button has text changed.

Maybe i'm doing something stupid or just missing something in the algorithm, at the moment i'm stuck.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: why you are taking the button array ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are confused, `getView()` is executed once per *visible* item. This is your code:

```
        vh.qnt=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qnt);

        vh.quantidade=new Quantidade[itens.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<itens.size();i++){
            b[i]=(Button)conv.findViewById(R.id.qnt);
            vh.quantidade[i].quantidade=1;
            vh.quantidade[i].order=i;
        }
```

`vh.qnt` and all instances of `b[i]` reference the exact same Button (`R.id.qnt`) *in the row that is being rendered*.

You also need to update the text of the button after the if/else, when update the rest of the `vh` views.

Comment: So i need to create more than one Button in the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I did it!!
I've used  setTag() and getTag(),  that allow me to use the same id (R.id.qnt) for different buttons. Here is the code:

```
int aux=0; //before onCreate()
```

.
.
.

```
vh.qnt.setTag(aux);//set a tag for each button in row
aux++;             //this will be the number of rows
vh.qnt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    int index=(Integer)vh.qnt.getTag();
                    Titem item=itens.get(index);
                    if(item.isCheck()){
                        vh.qnt.setText(String.valueOf(vh.quantidade[index]++));

                    }
                }

            });
```

Thanks for the hint @dmon, you opened my eyes for the " same id " fact.